# Why does including tau.js in Tizen app break everything else?

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, tizen-web-app, samsung-galaxy

I'm working on an app for the Samsung Galaxy watch (Tizen version 4.0) using Tizen studio and I've run into a frustrating issue. To give you some background, Samsung places a lot of emphasis on using their [Tizen Advanced UI](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/user-interface/tizen-advanced-ui) framework in mobile and wearable apps. This framework supposedly makes it easy to add standard UI components to your projects.

The issue I'm running into is that as soon as I add the tau.js script to my project, nearly everything else stops working. This is pretty annoying because the TAU library does offer some helpful things like the circle-helper which makes scrolling lists on the Samsung watch super easy with the Bezel.

In my project, I added a click listener to one of the spans on this page ("Current").
[image]
Without the tau.js script added, clicking on the span does exactly what I want. As soon as I add the script however (I've tried adding it in the head and body section, above and below my own script), no clicks are ever registered. It's as if the tau.js script is blocking my own script.

Another interesting thing is that when I add the tau.js file, my accelerometer values are no longer produced and everything reads zero. If I add the accelerometer-reading script to the bottom of the tau.js file it will work but the click functionality still doesn't work.

Finally, I have been able to add a click listener to the document as a whole like this:

```
document.addEventListener("click",myFunction);
```

That works fine but it's driving me crazy that I can't add event listeners to any other HTML elements.

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/Javascript so maybe I'm missing something fundamental. What would cause one script to override another script? Why does adding the tau.js file seem to ruin everything? [You can find the tau.js code here](https://github.com/Samsung/TAU). Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Tizen 4.0 and the TAU files (CSS/Js) I'm using are the ones that were generated by Tizen Studio when I first created my project. Updated my question to include the version.

Comment: How do You add listeners? Please share Your code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my problem by moving all of my code to one html file and using [TAU page management](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.ui.practices/html/web/tau/managing_page_w.htm). It looked like this listener...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function()
```

wasn't being triggered when I navigated to the new page. Adding all of the javascript files to one page fixed my issue.

Comment: any multi file solutions yet? could you share a git repo?